# Part of the brain that forms two ע

Tags: tefilin

I remember reading an interesting article about the mitzvah of teffilin. They had a fascinating picture of what the front of the brain looks like . In the picture it shows that their appears to be two ע that are formed in the brain. Then they show that the teffilin happen to have to be placed betweem these ע(literally bein einecha)since it is the same place as the halacha requires.

I understand this question seems strange,but after seeing the picture it will make sense. Does someone happen to know where this picture is,or knows enough about the brain that they can show any picture with these ע?

Comment: Do you remember the title of the website or newspaper you read the article on/in?

Comment: it was a web article that I read probably 10 years ago

Comment: Then it is quite possible the article has been deleted or the website terminated. Web articles do not last forever.

Comment: I understand that,but maybe someone else remebers the article or how these ע look on a reg brain picture

Comment: Was the Ayin in Ivri or Ashuri?

Comment: Ashuri script...

Answer (score 3):

You could be referring to this. The optic nerves do form 2 ayins (or rather an X).

This picture is from under the brain looking up.
https://classconnection.s3.amazonaws.com/609/flashcards/1653609/jpg/optic_nerve1352774153907.jpg

This X forms at eye level and below so tefillin do not go on this structure unless you actually wear them between they eyes.

Comment: thanks because of your answeer I was able to find the right pic

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @clinteastwood I found the right picture which I remember depicting the ayins. One can see the both ayins in the picture. The teffilin I would assume sit in between the ayins on the chisam.Which seems to correlate to the right part of the head to place teffilin al pi halacha.So bein ainayim literally  [image][image][image]
 [image]

Comment: The Chiasm is at eye level. You don't put tefillin there.

Comment: I am missing somthing ,placing the teffilin on top of the head what would correspond to that place of the brain,beacuse Insaw another picture which shows the ears on the sides amd it seems that its the correect place

Comment: @clinteastwood ,see the picture I added,I am not sure if you understood what I meant

Comment: thats bettersdgfagga